# Keyboard needs to be setup on every boot up

Tags: snow-leopard, keyboard

I am being asked to setup my keyboard every time I reboot my computer. Is there anyway I can get this to keep the setup?

I am on Snow Leopard and have a Logitech Wave wireless keyboard and mouse combo. This started happening when I switched to 64-bit mode. Booting into 32-bit mode doesn't fix it.

Comment: Is it a bluetooth keyboard? And does this Apple link http://support.apple.com/kb/TA23441?viewlocale=en_US by chance help at all?

Comment: No, it has it's own receiver.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Um, standard "stock" fixes:

- Repair permissions
- Check logs
- Erase (Logitech) software and reinstall

You could also see if it is actually saving the connection details (by finding the pref file) or it is unable to.

Comment: How do I repair permissions and where are the logs?

Answer (score 2):

Repair permissions: Run Disk Utility; select your (main) disk; click Repair Disk Permissions

Viewing logs: Run Console